# Asking for readline library while Installing rlwrap in linux

Tags: linux, rlwrap

I'm following this tutorial for installing `rlwrap` for `sql*plus` on linux. But it gives me an error
 
[image: error] 

I'm quit new to linux and I tryied installing readline library apartly. It executed without errors, But it didn't help to this. What will be the wrong. Must the readline libray be installed in a specific location? or else?

Comment: What system do you have? Did you install readline by compiling it yourself or did you use the `apt-get` repositories like this: `sudo apt-get install libreadline6 libreadline6-dev`?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. System means? It's in redhat linux on a virtual machine. No, not from repositories. Manually.

Comment: Then try again to install `readline` with `yum install readline-devel`. Then try installing `rlwrap` again.

Comment: must I install it within a same directory or in separate directories are ok?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I installed it correctly. Problem was in the installation of Oracle. I corrected it.

Comment: It would be nice to have an answer for linking a from-source installation of readline lib to a from-source installation of rlwrap. I did set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to no avail